# Managed package installation error

Tags: apex, managed-package

We are facing an issue while installing a managed package in a new developer edition organization. 
When I try to install it in a developer org I get the following error :

> 1. (Opportunity-Opportunity Layout) duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id:  Opportunity-Opportunity
>      Layout: duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record
>      with id:

I have gone through most of the links but still no solution.

Comment: Is this an AppExchange package? Contacting the vendor directly is normally useful in that case.

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thanks for the replay !
The Package which we want to install is not an AppExchange package.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not typical apex error so we will have to follow trial and error method:

1. Remove all customization from org related to Opportunity Layout. Retry to install.
2. Create fresh dev org and try to install packages on it
3. If both of above did not work then contact package owner take their help.